# ClassPathLoader can't find native lib with ABI=arm64-v8a

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm developing an native app for my Samsung Galaxy A5 2016.
The app works fine when I set the ABI to armabi-v7a. Now I would like to improve the speed of the native operations and therefore I tried to set the ABI to arm64-v8a. Since my phone uses a Cortex-A53 CPU this should  be fine but when I run the app I get the following exception:

```
08-21 19:18:11.251 9743-9743/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: tum.ei.lmt.orbslamapp, PID: 9743
                                                 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/tum.ei.lmt.orbslamapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/tum.ei.lmt.orbslamapp-1/lib/arm, /data/app/tum.ei.lmt.orbslamapp-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libnative-lib.so"
                                                     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
                                                     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1567)
                                                     at tum.ei.lmt.orbslamapp.NativeInterface.<clinit>(NativeInterface.java:6)
                                                     at tum.ei.lmt.orbslamapp.MainActivity.onCameraViewStarted(MainActivity.java:234)
                                                     at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.processEnterState(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:323)
                                                     at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.checkCurrentState(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:313)
                                                     at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.surfaceChanged(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:198)
                                                     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:668)
                                                     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:172)
                                                     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1013)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2555)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1550)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7190)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:959)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

It seems that the PathClassLoader can't find the libnative-lib.
Here a snippet of the Gradle build console:

```
    Build native-lib arm64-v8a
    [1/13] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/featureCompression/DBoW2/FeatureVector.cpp.o
    [2/13] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main
    ...
    [13/13] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/arm64-v8a/libnative-lib.so
```

Does anyone know how i can tell the ClassPathLoader where the libnative-lib.so is or help me with any other suggestion. 
Thank you.

Interesting part of my gradle file:

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments "-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=24", "-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a", "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
            cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++0x -Wno-deprecated -ftree-vectorize -ffast-math"

            //abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips', 'mips64'
            //abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
```

The whole CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include_directories(/home/alex/Android/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include)
add_library(opencv-lib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(opencv-lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jni/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/NativeInterface.cpp
             ...
             src/main/cpp/featureCompression/DUtils/Timestamp.cpp
             )

target_compile_options(native-lib PUBLIC
    "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O3>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O3>"
)

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib
              log )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                       opencv-lib
                       ${log-lib} )
```

Comment: Can you tried to check something like this:
adb shell "getprop | grep abi"
(the abi's that your device is support)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to y30 for the help. It seem that my phone doesn't support arm64-v8a. So I guess there is nothing I can do?

[The output of "getprop | grep abi"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ffK2.png)